# Multiple foreign keys pointing to same table in Entity Framework are indistinguisible

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm unable to distinguish between foreign keys when two or more point to the same table through the database context.

For example, if I have a db with two tables, Users and Invoices.

```
Users has two fields: userId and userName
Invoices has three fields: invoiceNumber, cashierUserId, supervisorUserId
```

cashierUserId and supervisorUserId are foreign keys pointing to userId in the Users table.

Now in entity framework via the db context when I try to get the cashier or supervisor's user name I can't tell which user name I'm going to get.

```
dbContext.Invoices.Single(i => i.invoiceNumber == 1).Users.userName;
```

Which user name do I get? The cashier's or the supervisor's? How do I tell it which one I want?

Comment: Are you shure you don't have Users and Users1?

Comment: I could suggest you break down your design. Meaning to create each table for Cahier and Supervisor

Comment: The design is just to clearly illustrate the problem.

Comment: Gusman - I checked for that. The only navigation property is Users. However there should be three based on the number of FKs in the db linked to Users.

Comment: Are you using code first or db first?

Answer (score 0):

First off, your code has an issue. The "Users" collection wouldn't have a property called "userName". It should probably read:

```
dbContext.Invoices.Single(i => i.invoiceNumber == 1).Users.First().userName;
```

Obviously, .First() is not going to help with the "distinguishing" problem. For that, I see two solutions:

1. Modify your context so each navigation property has a special name ("Cashier", "Supervisor"). Then you would just write:

   ```
   dbContext.Invoices.Single(i => i.invoiceNumber == 1).Cashier.userName;
   ```
2. Give your user a "type" field. This could be a string stored in the user table, or likely a foreign key into a "UserTypes" table (in a normalized database). Then your query becomes:

   ```
   dbContext.Invoices.Single(i => i.invoiceNumber == 1).Users.First(u => u.UserType == "Cashier").userName;
   ```

Using a different table would change the predicate a bit, but you get the idea. To help guide your design, remember that EF isn't very different than standard SQL. How would you craft a standard SQL query to distinguish the two? You would base it on foreign key (the first option), or another field on the users table (the second option).